# Implement checkbox on UITableViewCell - Swift

Tags: uitableview, swift

I am building a ToDo List type app, and I would like to place an editable checkbox in each cell in the UITableView. I want the user to be able to mark the item as completed by tapping the checkbox in the tableView. They also need to be able to tap in the cell, outside of the checkbox, and segue to a detail view.

So far I have created a custom cell class. The plan was to display an image of an unchecked box, and when the user taps the image, the image is swapped with a different image of a checked box (and the item is updated appropriately).

I tried putting a Touch Gesture Recognizer on the image, but it didn't work.  Whenever the image on the cell is tapped, it just segues to the detail view. Then I found an article somewhere that says to create UIView nested inside the cell and link the Touch Gesture to that.  So I tried that, but now it only work intermittently. Sometimes it recognizes the touch correctly, and sometimes it just segues to the detail view.

I've seen this idea in the Wunderlist app.

How do I go about implementing this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

iOS doesn't have a native checkbox control. Apple uses a UISwitch instead.

If you want to follow Apple's HIG, use a switch.

If you want a checkbox style instead, you have several options.

You can attach a gesture recognizer to an image view and do it that way.

You can create a custom subclass of UIButton (MyCheckbox).

You can find a third party checkbox class that somebody else already created. I would look on [**Cocoa Controls**](https://www.cocoacontrols.com). A quick search reveals half-a-dozen different checkbox options.

An important thing is the size of the "hit box" that the user taps. You usually want to create an image/view that's at least 30x30 points in size, and 40x40 points is better. An easy way to do that is to create your checked and unchecked images with enough whitespace around them to make them 30x30 or 40x40 points.

My guess is that your image view is too small and that's why you report that it is only working intermittently.